# Isotope gutter/spacing on page load, no gutter/spacing on window resize

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

On page load, isotope adds a gutter between my isotope items. When I resize the window, even 1px, it will fix the layout.

I've been racking my brain as to why isotope is adding extra spacing between my images. It does this on only 1 page, and the code is identical to the other pages, with the only exception being that I'm loading in slightly larger jpg images for this page.

I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/cvanorman/pen/ojBzBo) with my code/dependencies so you'll see that it works there. If you have tips on improving my code, please let me know.

Here's my isotope function:

```
/**
 * Item Filter
 *
 */
itemFilter: function(isoContainer, $isoSelector) {
    var itemGroup;
    var viewBySelect;
    var nameFilter;
    var buttonFilter;
    var usedNames = {};

    var $isoContainer = $(isoContainer);

    var $win = $(window);
    // Lazy load w/ sorting/filtering enabled
    var $imgs = $('.lazy');
    // init Isotope
    var $container = $isoContainer.isotope({
        itemSelector: $isoSelector,
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        animationEngine: 'best-available',
        getSortData: {
            name: '.name'
        },
        filter: function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            var itemGroupResult = itemGroup ? $this.is(itemGroup) : true;
            var viewBySelectResult = viewBySelect ? $this.is(viewBySelect) : true;
            var nameFilterResult = nameFilter ? $this.is(nameFilter) : true;
            var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is(buttonFilter) : true;

            return itemGroupResult && viewBySelectResult && nameFilterResult && buttonResult;
        }
    });

    // Fixes layout issues when images are still loading.
    $container.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
        $container.isotope('layoutItems');
    });

    // Load images when filtering is initiated and 
    // we have a new HTML layout to lazyload on.
    $container.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete', function () {
        FEATURES.loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
    });

    // Load images on scroll with event lazylazy.
    $win.on('scroll', function () {
        FEATURES.loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
    });

    // Initialize lazyload with fadeIn effect and failure_limit.
    // Listening on event 'lazylazy'
    $imgs.lazyload({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        failure_limit: Math.max($imgs.length - 1, 0),
        event: 'lazylazy'
    });

    // select filtering - by Role
    $('.view-by-select').on('change', function() {
        viewBySelect = $('option:selected', this).data('filter');
        $container.isotope();
    });

    // filtering - by Profile Name
    $('.filter-title').on('click', 'span', function() {
        nameFilter = $(this).hasClass('name');
        $container.isotope({ sortBy: nameFilter });
    });

    // reset filtering
    $('.filter-reset').on('click', function() {
        $('.view-by-select').val('default').trigger('change');
        buttonFilter = $(this).data('filter');
        $container.isotope();
    });

    // Remove duplicate roles from select list
    var $selectList = $('select.view-by-select > option');
    $selectList.each(function () {
        if(usedNames[this.text]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
        }
    });

}
```

Here's an image of the issue I'm experiencing:

[image: image gutters are present when they shouldn't be]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any gutter present in your codepen. On another note,  animationEngine is not in isotope v2, only v1.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. my solution is dirty at best:

```
itemFilter: function(isoContainer, $isoSelector) {
    var $win = $(window);
    $win.load(function() {
        var itemGroup;
        var viewBySelect;
        var nameFilter;
        var buttonFilter;
        var usedNames = {};

        var $isoContainer = $(isoContainer);


        // Lazy load w/ sorting/filtering enabled
        var $imgs = $('.lazy');

        // init Isotope
        var $container = $isoContainer.isotope({
            itemSelector: $isoSelector,
            layoutMode: 'fitRows',
            animationEngine: 'best-available',
            getSortData: {
                name: '.name'
            },
            filter: function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                var itemGroupResult = itemGroup ? $this.is(itemGroup) : true;
                var viewBySelectResult = viewBySelect ? $this.is(viewBySelect) : true;
                var nameFilterResult = nameFilter ? $this.is(nameFilter) : true;
                var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is(buttonFilter) : true;

                return itemGroupResult && viewBySelectResult && nameFilterResult && buttonResult;
            }
        });
        $container.isotope('layout');

        // Fixes layout issues when images are still loading.
        $container.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
            $container.isotope('layoutItems');
        });

        // Load images when filtering is initiated and 
        // we have a new HTML layout to lazyload on.
        $container.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete', function () {
            FEATURES.loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
        });

        // Load images on scroll with event lazylazy.
        $win.on('scroll', function () {
            FEATURES.loadVisible($imgs, 'lazylazy');
        });

        // Initialize lazyload with fadeIn effect and failure_limit.
        // Listening on event 'lazylazy'
        $imgs.lazyload({
            effect: "fadeIn",
            failure_limit: Math.max($imgs.length - 1, 0),
            event: 'lazylazy'
        });

        // select filtering - by Role
        $('.view-by-select').on('change', function() {
            viewBySelect = $('option:selected', this).data('filter');
            $container.isotope();
        });

        // filtering - by Profile Name
        $('.filter-title').on('click', 'span', function() {
            nameFilter = $(this).hasClass('name');
            $container.isotope({ sortBy: nameFilter });
        });

        // reset filtering
        $('.filter-reset').on('click', function() {
            $('.view-by-select').val('default').trigger('change');
            buttonFilter = $(this).data('filter');
            $container.isotope();
        });

        // Remove duplicate roles from select list
        var $selectList = $('select.view-by-select > option');
        $selectList.each(function () {
            if(usedNames[this.text]) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
            }
        });

    });
}
```

I wrapped my entire isotope script in a `$(window).load()` function. That fixes the layout issue on page load. Anyone have a better solution?